How to get color palette from a .ase file in Python?
I'm trying to write a Python script to extract a color palette from .ase (Adobe Swatch Exchange) file, forming an array of all the colors in the palette in hex format.
How can this be done?

The swatch package can do this.
You can write:
swatch.parse(filename)

To get a dictionary with info about the file.
Example Dictionary:
{
    'name': u'color name',
    'type': u'Process',
    'data': {
        'mode': u'RGB',
        'values': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
